# Magento Multiple Stores - Parent / Child

Tags: magento

I have installed Magento and would like to set up 1 parent and 2 child stores.

Similar to:

```
magento-mall.com – listing everything (ie Furniture, Electronics, Apparel)
  magento-furniture.com – only listing furniture.
  magento-electronics.com - only listing Electronics
```

I have setup the following:

Categories:

```
Main Store
  Furniture Store
    Furniture Category 1
    Furniture Category 2
  Computer Store
    Computer Category 1
    Computer Category 2
```

I would like to set up 3 websites (example domains), as follows:

```
main-store.com
  furniture-store.com
  computers-store.com
```

- main-store.com - points to the Main Store root category and thus listing ALL the items (ie both Furniture and Computers)
- furniture-store.com - points to the Furniture Store Category – ie only lists Furniture items.
- computers-store.com - points to the Computers Store Category – ie only lists Computer items.

**Problem:**

When creating the furniture-store.com using Magento's "System/Manage Stores/Create Store" the only available Root Category option is "Main Store". This would have furniture-store.com list both the furniture and the computer items.

**My question is:**

What do I need to do to make the furniture-store.com only list items from the Furniture Store category (whilst at the same time allowing main-store.com to list everything)?

Note: the stores are to share the same usernames and stock etc.

**Edit:** I'm looking for a PHP, Javascript or HTML solution on how I can make furniture-store.com only list items from the Furniture Store category rather then the root category.

Comment: Kindly reopen: The question relates to programming - I'm looking for a PHP, Javascript or HTML solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just reorganize your categories. Now you have the only one root category - Main Store. Get rid of it. Make two root categories – Furniture Store and Computer Store.

Comment: Note: to share users between websites, go to System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Account sharing options -> set Share Customer Accounts to Global

Comment: If I use "two root categories – Furniture Store and Computer Store" how do I make the Main Store (main-store.com) list items from both Furniture and Computer root categories?

Comment: Well, you can add third category 'both' and place all products in it.